# Passing output of a method to another method in Python

Tags: python, oop

I am new to concepts of objects and classes; i was wondering is there any better way to access output of a method and pass it to another?

```
class cafec_param:

    def __init__(self,precip,pe,awc,nmonths):

        self.precip = precip
        self.pe = pe
        self.awc = awc
        self.nmonths = nmonths

    def AWC(self):

        if self.awc<254:
            Ss = self.awc
            Su = 0
        else:
            Ss = 254; Su = self.awc-254
        AWC = Ss + Su
        return AWC,Ss,Su

    def test(self):
        p = cafec_param.AWC(self)[0]
        return p
```

What are possible ways to pass, say, Ss and Su into another method?
Thanks

Comment: Like you would do it with regular functions. Get the return value of method1 and pass it into method2.

Comment: Also, does the code have anything to do with the question? Currenlty it looks like it's here just for good measure.

Comment: Hi, I just wanted to get rid off cafec_param.AWC(self)[0] every time I need Ss!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call said method from inside AWC:

```
   def AWC(self):

        if self.awc<254:
            Ss = self.awc
            Su = 0
        else:
            Ss = 254; Su = self.awc-254
        AWC = Ss + Su
        this.your_method(Ss, Su)
        return AWC,Ss,Su
```

or get the output of AWC in the code that calls AWC and then pass Ss and Su to your method:

```
cparam = cafec_param(precip,pe,awc,nmonths)
AWCres, Ss, Su = cparam.AWC()
cparam.your_method(Ss, Su)
```

Please note that I used the names for the class, methods and variables that you specified so that my answer is easier to understand. However, you should probably take a look at [Python's naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to make your code more readable and easier to understand and maintain.

Hope I helped! :)

Comment: Thanks, wish I could upvote it, but lack reputations.

Comment: I'm glad. You can pick my answer as the answer for this question if you like.

Answer (score 2):

A better approach to call a method inside another method in a class.

```html
class cafec_param:

    def __init__(self,precip,pe,awc,nmonths):

        self.precip = precip
        self.pe = pe
        self.awc = awc
        self.nmonths = nmonths

    def AWC(self):

        if self.awc<254:
            Ss = self.awc
            Su = 0
        else:
            Ss = 254; Su = self.awc-254
        AWC = Ss + Su
        return AWC,Ss,Su

    def test(self):
        return self.AWC()[0]



ee=cafec_param('re',34,56,2)
print(ee.test())
```